# Applescript to refresh all the calendars in iCal

Tags: applescript, icalendar

I tried this code to refresh all the calendars in iCal(Shift-Command-R), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
tell application "iCal"
    launch
    reload calendars
end tell
```

What's the Applescript command to do this?

Comment: your code doesn't get any errors why do you think it's not working ?

Comment: @mcgrailm : There was no error, when I ran this script. Just nothing happened. I had to click Shift-Command-R to refresh iCal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that the functionality isn't built into the iCal dictionary. I couldn't find anything other than the `reload calendars` command you're already using. You're only other option would be to use [GUI scripting](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html) to select the menu item or press the key combination.

```
tell application "iCal" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iCal"
        keystroke "r" using {command down, shift down}
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: I've edited the script to activate iCal first, which seems to work on my machine.